# JSON object - ordering of elements

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I do know that `JSON` ordering inside objects do not matter. But I've observed that the ordering of `JSON` elements in the response in a public api changes , according to the different code-path that the server follows internally. I see this as a security vulnerability and went ahead and fixed it so that the response always has the same ordering of elements in `JSON`. Now  I'm trying to write a test case so that I can verify that the two jsons have the same ordering in mocha using the requests module. I can't quiet get hold of how to do it. My intial take take was to do

```
arrays_equal( Object.keys(res1.body), Object.keys(res2.body))
```

*`arrays_equal` is a custom implementation which checks if array is equal or not.

This does not work.

Once the response is parsed into a javascript object, it makes a hashtable internally, loosing all the ordering information. What is the best way to handle this ?

**EDIT 1**

Here is a hypothetical example

When I login as an admin user (from chrome developer tools, response string),
My response is `{username:'blah', famous:true}`

When I login as a normal user,
My response is `{famous:true, username:'blah'}`

Now I made a fix by changing a code little bit so that both logins return `{username:'blah', famous:true}`.

Now I need to write a test to verify that both the response has the same key order in the *json response string*.

Comment: Can you share the custom implementation of `arrays_equal`? Also, you are just interested in checking if the property names are consistent and not the values, right?

Comment: This is one of the case of *too much over-engineering*. Objects are not sorted in any specific order. So even if you send in specific order, there is no guarantee that you will receive in same order. Also as you know ordering in objects do not matter, check if both objects have same keys instead of same order keys

Comment: *What is the best way to handle this ?* Some more info required, do you wish to do so for every response from the API?

Comment: @rajesh i dont agree. While it is not guaranteed that objects are ordered, there is no guarantee that they are unordered, so i think the OP is right that it can expose the internal code structure.

Comment: @gurvinder372 It doesn't matter what the implementation of arrays_equal is. Abstractly it means compare whether the arrays are equal

Comment: @Malice It matters when you say that *This does not work.* Also, it is not clear as to why **ordering of keys** matters to you. You are not going to access the values by index, you access them by keys. And if your test case is first fetching `Object.keys` and then first accessing keys by index, then you can always sort the the keys first to ensure consistency of order of keys.

Comment: @Rajesh We don't have control over what order is sent. But it is guaranteed that the order in which it was sent is what is received (network doesnt change the order). You can just print response in string (may be on chrome developer tools) instead of res object in node.js client to see what I'm getting at.

Comment: @gurvinder372 The idea of the above code is that the arrays returned on object.keys will always be of same order even if the response order changes.

Comment: @Malice No. JSON is a string. When this string in parsed into Object, then order can change. There is no guarantee. So if you want ordered keys, you can create an array of keys and use it to retrieve the values in specific order.

Comment: @Malice In that case, just sort the output of `Object.keys` and you will be fine.

Comment: Edited question

Comment: @Rajesh  edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 const sort(a,b) => a.index - b.index;

 const keys = Object.keys(JSON.parse( json1 )),
   map1 = keys.map(key =>  ({key, index: json1.indexOf(key)})).sort(sort),
   map2 = keys.map(key => ({key, index: json2.indexOf(key)})).sort(sort),    
   result = map1.every(({key}, index) => key === map2[index].key});
```

You could check the objects string if the keys are in order.

Comment: 1) Would the key order remain the same after `Object.keys(JSON.parse( json1 ))`

2) You assume that I've `json1` and `json2`. Or Is there a way to get it from the requests module ?

Comment: @malice 1) yes 2) the two json strigs you want to compare ;)